# Keeping MongoDB Size From Inflating in SaaS Product & DB Costs Down

Tags: javascript, mongodb, saas, database

I'm new to MongoDB and database storage for web applications in general.

It seems that if you have a SaaS and a number of clients that continually add data to their online dashboards, your database will continually inflate.

And since the cost of database hosting rises steeply with increased DB size, hosting costs will increase while number of clients does not increase.

eg In mLab, 1GB storage is $15/mo.

Over a number of years, is there a good way to keep database size/costs stable while allowing your clients to access old information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. By definition, if you want to access data you have to store it. To decrease what you're storing, you have to purge it. Once you purge it, you can't access it.

Once you reach a certain threshold, it becomes more cost-effective to just buy a server and pay a colocation facility to host it (when you hit around 100USD/Mo is about where that point is likely to be).

Once you're to the point where you need multiple hosts, it can start making sense to look at sharding the data based on recency. New data on fast SSD (expensive) so it's readily available, and old data on much less expensive large spinning-disks (bigger and cheaper).

This type of setup really isn't an option at the levels you talking about though.

Comment: Is there any way to store it at lower cost, then? How would an app like Asana or Facebook deal with this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Asana, but Facebook doesn't buy space the same way you're talking about. They mostly run their own datacenters. Even when you're to the point of paying a colocation facility for space for your own (self provided) server this type of pricing goes out the window. You just slap in bigger disks.

Comment: Ah OK I understand. Until an app reaches large scale production (and running a datacenter would make sense), costs per client will keep increasing as DB size grows, unless you automatically purge old data, or ask them to archive their data and purge from DB.

Comment: Even before then, there are a number of companies which run data centers, which allow you to bring in your own servers. You only play for the power/network/number of U your occupying. This can be more cost-effective than (or in conjunction with) shared services if your baseline usage is high enough.

Comment: OK Cool - thanks! I suppose the app could send old data to some kind of low-cost 'archive' key value database that could be accessed more slowly, as well.